# How to assign ENS primary name to Smart Contract?

Tags: ens

I'm seeing similar questions that say 'yes, you can do it', but not precisely how.

The issue I'm having is that I can send/transfer a ENS to a new owner. In this case the smart contract.

But then it seems I would need to connect with the Smart Contract wallet to the ENS website to set ENS that was transferred to 'me' to the the primary name. Obviously (?) I can't with a smart contract. Bc I don't have the private key of the smart contract I created, so there's no way to import into metamask or similar?

I'm pretty sure I must be overlooking something.